# I want to store the output of the below command in an variable

Tags: linux

I want to store the output of the below command in an variable
This is my cmd

```
load=$(sar -q | awk -F'[\t] +\\' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7 }')
```

When I am trying to store the output in an variable I am getting like this inux

```
3.13.0-45-generic
(vr1tel-Inspiron-3542)
03/27/2015
_i686_
(4
CPU)
06:47:44
AM
LINUX
RESTART
06:55:01
AM
runq-sz
plist-sz
ldavg-1
ldavg-5
ldavg-15
blocked
07:05:01
AM
2
449
1.08
1.01
0.76
0
07:15:01
AM
3
438
1.09
1.11
0.93
0
07:25:01
AM
0
434
0.29
0.69
0.85
0
```

Average:

```
2
440
0.82
0.94
```

but I want answer like this

Linux 3.13.0-45-generic (vr1tel-Inspiron-3542)  03/27/2015  *i686*  (4 CPU)

```
06:47:44 AM       LINUX RESTART      

06:55:01 AM   runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15   blocked      
07:05:01 AM         2       449      1.08      1.01      0.76         0      
07:15:01 AM         3       438      1.09      1.11      0.93         0      
07:25:01 AM         0       434      0.29      0.69      0.85         0      
Average:            2       440      0.82      0.94      0.85         0      

08:08:13 AM       LINUX RESTART      

08:34:19 AM       LINUX RESTART      

08:35:01 AM   runq-sz  plist-sz   ldavg-1   ldavg-5  ldavg-15   blocked      
08:45:01 AM         0       437      0.26      0.51      0.46         1      
08:55:01 AM         0       418      0.30      0.32      0.40         0      
09:05:01 AM         0       348      1.18      0.60      0.48         0      
09:15:01 AM         0       364      0.23      0.55      0.55         0      
09:25:01 AM         0       364      0.42      0.39      0.46         0      
09:35:01 AM         0       439      0.33      0.26      0.34         0      
09:45:01 AM         0       469      0.38      0.40      0.36         0
```

Comment: you redirect the output to a tmp file.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr aggreed. `$(sar -q | awk -F'[\t] +\\' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7 }') > out.txt` should work

Comment: @Harika Actually all the new lines are there. Try `echo "$load"` and you will see them. When the variable is not quoted it's not showing the newlines.

Comment: @divaka they are gone if you keep `IFS` as it is.

Comment: It should work just fine. You need to quote the variable when printing it, though: `echo "$load"`.

Comment: its working.but when i am using  with for loop it is printing in different format